# Repeat cursor text in a custom Emmet snippet

Tags: code-snippets, emmet

I want to create a snippet where the the text I type at the first cursor position gets used multiple times. I thought I could do it this way by repeating a cursor position number but it just treats the other ones as independent cursor positions. I don't see anything in the documentation about this.

Here is an example of what I would like to work:

```
<template id=${1}>
   This is a ${1}!
</template>

<style>
   #${1} {${2}}
</style>
```

Here is my Emmet snippets file used in VS Code:

```
{
    "html": {
      "snippets": {
        "test": "test[id=${1}]>{This is a ${1}.}"
      }
    }
}
```

When I use the 'test' snippet it puts the cursor at the first ${1} but anything I type is not reflected in the second ${1} it stays empty.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on editor you’re using. If your editor fully supports text fields (like Sublime Text, VSCode) the example above should work, all `${N}` with same `N` should be connected.

Comment: I am using VS Code and it doesn't work. 

Comment: It‘s a good idea to write what you actually did, step-by-step

Comment: OK, well I added the example snippet I tried to use in VS Code and explained what happened.

Comment: Looks like a bug in VSCode, you should report issue there. They must be linked together

Comment: Hmm, darn. OK. Thanks.